Select by charset field only matches when using trim or ilike
I have this table:
dbchatbot=# \d messages
                            Table "public.messages"
     Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 uuid            | character varying(36)       |           | not null | 
 content         | text                        |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "messages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (uuid)
    "messages_uuid_idx" UNIQUE, btree (uuid)

*(I know I should be using a uuid type field, but I am inheriting this table and I can not change this.)
Some times when I am querying by uuid the match fails:
select uuid from messages where uuid = '3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL';
 uuid 
------
(0 rows)

It works if I use ilike:
select uuid from messages where uuid ilike '3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL';
          uuid          
------------------------
 3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL
(1 row)

Or if I trim the field value:
select uuid from messages where trim(uuid) = '3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL';
          uuid          
------------------------
 3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL
(1 row)

It doesn't fail in all records of the table:
select uuid from messages where uuid = '3wvMFFjZLD4aIsj64yLScA';
          uuid          
------------------------
 3wvMFFjZLD4aIsj64yLScA
(1 row)

I can not use ilike or trim because I am using a ORM and I don't want to mess up with the primary keys default search.
How can I fix the issue?
Update
Another example to demonstrate that there is not leading or trailing spaces:
select "uuid", length("uuid"), '>' || "uuid" || '<' AS debug_uuid  from messages where "uuid" ilike '3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL';
          uuid          | length |        debug_uuid        
------------------------+--------+--------------------------
 3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL |     22 | >3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL<
(1 row)

More weird the db doesn't return any record by this filter:
select uuid from messages where uuid <> trim(uuid);
 uuid 
------
(0 rows)

Update 2
More tests:
select uuid, length(uuid), length(trim(uuid)) from messages where length(uuid) <> length(trim(uuid));
 uuid | length | length 
------+--------+--------
(0 rows)

select uuid, encode(uuid::bytea, 'hex') as uuid_hex, encode('3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL', 'hex') as uuid_hex  from messages where trim(uuid) = '3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL';
          uuid          |                   uuid_hex                   |                   uuid_hex                   
------------------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------
 3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL | 3355556b434d497733497a725975774c6e657a44764c | 3355556b434d497733497a725975774c6e657a44764c
(1 row)


Update3
It is not the field. It is the index that has an issue. If I deactivate the indexes the query returns the record:
BEGIN;

SET LOCAL enable_indexscan = OFF;
SET LOCAL enable_bitmapscan = OFF;

select uuid from messages where uuid = '3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL';
          uuid          
------------------------
 3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL
(1 row)

COMMIT;


At the very least add a check constraint CHECK (uuid ~* '^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$')

For future reference: this could have tipped you off:

It works if [...] I trim the field value:
 select uuid from messages where trim(uuid) = '3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL';


You couldn't find any rows where uuid <> trim(uuid), so the only remaining explanation is the different query plan.
This query can use a plain index on the varchar column uuid:
... where uuid = '3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL';

But this one cannot, and will fall back to a sequential scan:
... where trim(uuid) = '3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL';

A look at the EXPLAIN output will show different query plans.
The index you see in the first query plan must be the culprit and REINDEX the solution (like you found yourself). Typically, just REINDEX on the index at fault is sufficient. But it won't hurt to REINDEX the whole table, i.e. all indexes of that table (if you can afford that).
Investigate the cause of the corruption. Especially if it happens more than once. Change of locale data in the underlying OS? Disruptive major upgrade? (The manual would instruct to recreate indexes.) Failing disk?
Of course, the data type uuid would be the proper solution in this case (as you noted yourself). It would also be immune to locale issues. Maybe you can switch after all? See:

Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars
What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?


The index was corrupted. Reindexing the table fixed the issue:
REINDEX TABLE messages;
REINDEX
select uuid from messages where uuid = '3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL';
          uuid          
------------------------
 3UUkCMIw3IzrYuwLnezDvL

